# What i Ctrl + O equivalent in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

In PyCharm for Mac I have opened a python file with many functions defined. The file is huge. What is the shortcut to list all available functions in the file and jump to any of them?

Comment: Did you try to use Navigate (View in older versions) | File Structure Popup (Ctrl+F12 on Windows) ?
 I think it's a close equivalent

Comment: Can you help me with the path for Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the 'File Structure Popup' CTRL+F12 (Windows) / CMD+F12 (Mac)

For further information, you have the [Jetbrains cheat sheet](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf), most bindings are common across their IDE's

Comment: Great, thanks. Do PyCharm has such cheat sheet, because I could not find one?

Comment: @John Yes there is, for both [Windows](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/pycharm/docs/PyCharm_ReferenceCard.pdf), and [Mac](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/pycharm/docs/PyCharm_ReferenceCard_mac.pdf).